# Overload/inject the lua runtime of a compiled program with custom lua/luajit

Tags: lua, static-libraries, luajit

I have a compiled program written in `C++` than embeds `lua5.1` and even exposes a lua REPL inside it. The program loads and runs a bunch of `.lua` scripts with source provided and editable. I do not have access to the `C++` (and possible other) source code of the program and do not intend to reverse-engineer it to then compile a modified version myself. I'd like to use `luaJIT` to improve runtime performance instead of the embedded `lua5.1` interpreter. Since `luaJIT` is API and ABI compatible with `lua5.1`, is it possible to somehow overload the embedded lua inside the program with `luaJIT` installed in my system (and how) at runtime?

Comment: If it's statically linked, no; if it's dynamically linked, you just have to switch out the library.

Comment: It is *probably* statically linked; there is no object/library file for lua shipped along with the package. The main package binary mentions lua a few times though, seen via a hex editor.

Comment: If it's statically linked, then you're out of luck, I'm afraid. Still, there was some way to list an executables library dependancies, try that and see if it has liblua.so in there

Comment: `readelf -d` shows library dependencies marking them as `NEEDED`. So I need to persuade the devs to either build with LuaJIT themselves or make it a dynamic library dependency.